# git setup with templates and restricted repositories

Tags: git, templates, version-control

I am quiet new to git, so maybe I haven't found the answer yet. I am currently evaluating if we can use git in our company (mainly for VHDL development). We are using CVS at the moment. The structure we have is:

- Project repo (including most of our VHDL projects)
- Restricted project repo (only some users have access to this repo)
- Template repo (e.g. for synthesis flow, simulation flow, testbench units, etc.)

The setup procedure of a new project is:

- create new repo
- check out the templates you need
- !!! Remove CVS link to templates !!!
- check everything into project repo
- Each user creates a sandbox

Due to the removal of the CVS link to the templates its pretty hard to get updates from the templates (e.g. bugfix in one testbench unit), or to bring back changes from the project. When looking at git, I did not find a straight forward way to:

- Check out a template
- Bring it into the project repo (where I can work on it)
- Push some changes into the official template repo

I don't think I can use branches, since restricted projects shall not be visible within the official template repos. In addition, the current flow for simulation and synthesis use a common directory for some files (the flow is based on Makefiles). I have arrived at two possibilities which could work for my purpose.

1. Create a merge repo, see [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlaBc.png)

   - Each project has a 'merge repo', where all the templates are cloned into (via git remote add). I know that this means that a push to a remote would check in the whole project.
2. Create clones of each used template and add them as submodules, see [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yX0At.png)

   - I am not sure how to deal with common/shared files for the flow

Below I tried to outline the overall structure of the two approaches. Any help is welcome.

EDIT:
I concluded that Gerrit Code Review can do the restrictions, and add additional features, that this solves my problems. I compared the structure of Gerrit with 2, and it is basically the same.

Comment: The workflow seems fairly specialized and complicated, especially (mis?)using repositories as workflow steps. You can setup restrictions with e.g. [gitolite](http://gitolite.com/). Branch restrictions are supported as well.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to gitolite. I started reading the documentation, when it pointed out that Gerrit can do restrictions as well. Since in the end I want to have a Code Review tool (+ Continuous Integration), I think I stick to Gerrit.